# How to decode unicode S3 object names?

Tags: amazon-s3, unicode, aws-sdk

How to decode unicode object names from S3 using the Windows C++ AWS SDK?

I'm facing the weird issue of getting wrongly decoded object names when listing buckets with files having unicode names. What I do is that I run 'mbstowcs_s' or 'MultiByteToWideChar' (Attempted both) to decode the object names that I get from S3.

As I understand, the object names coming from S3 are in multibyte format so I convert it to wide chars string using these converting functions, this seems to not work and I always get some trash names while listing unicode files, but names which use standard symbols from the ASCII table are properly decoded.

For example, having the file 'ธงไชย แม็คอินไตย์.txt' on my bucket, if I attempt to list it from S3 using ListObjectV2Request and I attempt to convert its name to wide chars using mbstowcs_s I always get some noise instead of a valid name. The same method works perfectly with ASCII name.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT 1:**

Here are a bit more details on how I'm attempting to decode the names (cutting off all the not relevant parts in order to focus on the decoding steps)

1) First I get the list of objects from S3:

```
pListObjectsOutcome = new Aws::S3::Model::ListObjectsV2Outcome(pS3Client->ListObjectsV2(*pObjectsRequest));
pObjectList = new (std::nothrow) Aws::Vector<Aws::S3::Model::Object>(pListObjectsOutcome->GetResult().GetContents());
```

2) Iterate over the list and extract the names:

```
Aws::Vector<Aws::S3::Model::Object>::iterator it = pObjectList->begin();
//loop for each name
Aws::String name = it->GetKey();
```

3) Now `name` contains one of the filenames, attempt to decode it:

```
PWCHAR* objectName = nullptr;
//Properly initialize objectName and szObjNameLen, then:
mbstowcs_s(&szCount, objectName, szObjNameLen, name.c_str(), name.length());
//OR:
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, name.c_str(), name.length(), objectName, szObjNameLen); //Using CP_UTF8 does not work as well
```

4) Later on, try to create a file on disk:

```
//Prepare the PATH for objectName and create the file...
hFile = CreateFile(objectName, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0,
     NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Using this procedure I'm able to create ASCII filenames but not unicode filenames.

Comment: Please show your code in how you are calling MultiByteToWideChar and how you are displaying the unicode strings. Include the type definitions for the vars.

Comment: @JohnHanley: Are the information I've provided sufficient to give some hint on this problem?

Comment: I think the issue with your code is that you are using CP_ACP. You should be using CP_UTF8 in your call to MultiByteToWideChar. The difference is that CP_ACP is an Ansi Code Page.

Comment: @JohnHanley is doesn't work either way.

Comment: Replace MB_PRECOMPOSED with 0.

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Which implementation of CreateFile are you compiling (CreateFileA or CreateFileW)? You need to be using CreateFileW (i.e. compiled and linked for unicode). What compiler are you using? What command line switches?